# convert unicodeScalars index to character index in a swift string

Tags: swift, string, parsing, nstextview

I have a parser that use the unicodeScalars view of a string to calculate indexes. From the result of the parser.
I have an `NSTextView` where I would like to place the caret depending of the result of the parser. Unfortunately, the `selectedRange` of the NSTextView is expecting a character index and not an unicodeScalar Index.

How can I convert the index from unicodeScalars to Characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  different string views share a common `String.Index`, and `NSRange(_:in:)` can be used to convert a `String` range to `NSRange` (which is what `selectedRange` needs). Example:

```
let str = "abcde"
if let idx = str.unicodeScalars.firstIndex(of: "") {
    let nsRange = NSRange(idx...idx, in: str)

    print(nsRange) // {6, 2}
    print((str as NSString).substring(with: nsRange)) // 
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of this NSRange capability! Awesome answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'init(_:in:)' with an argument list of type '(ClosedRange<Int>, in: String)'`when creating the range

Comment: @AP.: I tested the above code in my Xcode 10.2 before posting, it compiles and runs without problems.

Comment: which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @AP.: I tested it with Swift 5 (Xcode 10.2) and Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10.1)

Comment: Maybe it deserves a new question, but how can I get the opposite conversion?